# Can I create a date time column headers with default value in sqlite3?

Tags: java, sql, sqlite

I have been trying to create data time headers with default value in SQLite, However I don't know if this is possible in SQLite, a help would be appreciated. This is what I am trying to achieve:

[image]

Comment: It's not entirely clear what you want, but I suspect you want the wrong thing... probably your DB should have a single **Due** column, storing the date of whenever whatever you're storing is due; the _date-specific_ columns _feel_ more like they're part of how you _present_ the data (what's due in the upcoming week) _not_ something that should be stored in the database.

Comment: Where is the default value in the example? What is it that you actually want to achive?

Comment: The default value would be the dates in incremental order.